# Update form validators after form creation

Tags: typescript, angular

I am looking for a way to update form validators depending on user input.

For example I would want to add a `Validator.required` when the user selects a particular option in the form.

I have tried to rebuild the whole form using formBuilder but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.myForm.controls['controlName'].validator = isRequired ? Validator.required : null;
this.myForm.controls['controlName'].updateValueAndValidity();
```